# Dealing with adversarial grant committee members in interviews

Tags: funding, interview

I'm applying for a grant to research topic *foo* using *bar* as my working hypothesis (and it's not really something controversial: a lot of things are easier to deal with if you assume that *bar* is true). Now, one of the people sitting in the grant committee has published a couple of articles arguing that *bar* is horribly, irredeemably wrong, and we all should assume *quz* instead. This person is likely to raise this issue at the interview stage.

This doesn't worry me from a purely academic perspective: there are many ways of showing that this person's arguments don't hold water, and I can literally spend the rest of the day talking about them. However, it does worry me from a "I want that grant money" perspective: if I get that question, I'm going to have just a couple of minutes to state my case and get the rest of the committee (experts in my general field, but not in this particular narrow topic) to side with me. What would be an appropriate way of framing my reply?

**Update** --- The interview happened, the committee member in question raised this issue (just as I anticipated), and I replied along the lines that Sydney E. Everhart suggests below. The rest of the committee looked satisfied with this answer (as did some colleagues I had rehearsed the interview with a few days in advance), so in that sense, thank you, Sydney. Unfortunately, the committee member in question wasn't so impressed and gave a very negative evaluation of my proposal. I guess you can't convince someone that doesn't want to be convinced.

Comment: I am looking forward to this question. This problem, which I think boils down to differing schools within a community, comes up frequently in various forms, not only for grants (also: job interviews, PC meetings, etc.).

Comment: In my experience, most single-investigator sized grant programs don't do in-person interviews of the applicants in the US. What kind of grant (country, broad programs) are you applying for?

Comment: @BillBarth: you are right that this is not a US-based grant. For privacy reasons, I'd rather not say anything specific about these grants, other than the fact that shortlisted applicants are invited to a short interview with the committee.

Comment: Humanities, social science, engineering, physical science, mathematics? The more science-y the field, the more you can use evidence for *bar* rather than pure argument or opinion. There's no magic bullet to sway the other review panelists, but actual evidence is much harder to dispute. Either way, the fact that there is a *bar/quz* split is evidence that they should fund research on both sides until the issue is settled.

Comment: Let's just say that the use of LaTeX is widespread :) Again, it's not a matter of having data to show that *bar* is superior to *quz*; I could teach a semester-long course just about that. The issue here is to say something meaningful and memorable about the superiority of *bar* in just two minutes, such that non-experts can understand it. All the watertight arguments in the world are useless if I can't communicate them effectively.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am not in your field of work, however, as one of the comments to your question pointed out, this type of scenario can happen in other fields and situations.  The best first step is to acknowledge the debate and the limitations of your own study.  However, frame your response such that regardless of the debate, you will still learn something new.  For example, my response might be something like:

"Clearly there are two schools of thought as to whether *quz* or *bar* is the correct assumption, however, that question cannot be answered in a single study alone. By funding this proposal to do work under the assumption of *bar*, we can answer questions X, Y, and Z.  An additional outcome is that we will be providing more information about phenomena surrounding *bar*, thus providing more information that may ultimately help to answer the question of *quz* versus *bar*."